# mysql table data to csv file in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, export-to-csv

`````
````
<?php 

header('Content-Type: text/csv;');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="orderdata.csv";');
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
include_once $path . '/wp-config.php';
include_once $path . '/wp-load.php';
include_once $path . '/wp-includes/wp-db.php';
include_once $path . '/wp-includes/pluggable.php';
global $wpdb;
$ar=array();
$sql="SHOW COLUMNS FROM orders";
$res=$wpdb->get_results($sql);
foreach($res as $row){
    $ar[]=$row->Field;
}
$op=fopen("php://output", "w");  
fputcsv($op,$ar);  
$sql="SELECT * from orders";
$res=$wpdb->get_results($sql);
if(count($res)){
    foreach($res as $row){
        $row = (array)$row;
        fputcsv($op, $row);  
    }
}
fclose($op);



````
`````

/*
i want to download mysql table data into a csv file.. everything i did mentioned above .. but instead of downloading the csv file .. its printing the data i want to download.. and i dont know whats wrong with my code !!!! :(

```
Thanks in advance.
```

*/

Comment: place header in the start of the screen, also try to remove white spacing or extra line breaks.

Comment: @MuhammadAkberKhan  did as you suggested but the result is still same :(

Answer (score 0):

Please replace you header's with these lines , and then try. Basically there are semicolons passing in header which may alter values, also can you share the browser response content type?

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="orderdata.csv"');
```